# How to match field with another field of sub document in Mongo

Tags: mysql, mongodb

`mlb_players` is a collection having `dataId` as a field and a `teamData` as another sub document containing `teamId` and `dataId`.

Equivalent MySql: `SELECT p.playerId FROM mlb_players p INNER JOIN mlb_teams t ON p.dataId=t.dataId`

I want to convert this mysql query into equivalent of mongoDB.

Currently I am using below mongo query but giving an error:

```
db.getCollection('mlb_players').find({$where: "this.dataId == this.teamData.dataId"});
```

But it is giving me 0 records however with the same data in mysql is giving my 50 records.

For reference, the 1 of the document looks like:

```
{
 "_id" : ObjectId("55574d05e03ce60f64797432"),
 "dataId" : "87c484cc-e672-4a34-ab02-cc29101d8a52",
 "teamId" : "TB",
 "posId" : "SS",
 "playerName" : "Nick Franklin",
 "playerNameAbbr" : "N. Franklin",
 "playerJersey" : 2,
 "playerStatus" : "D",
 "playerSalary" : 5500,
 "salarySuggest" : 0,
 "playerProj" : 0.0,
 "playerAvg" : 0.0,
 "manualSalary" : 1,
 "playerImg" : 0,
 "hasImage" : 0,
 "used" : 0,
 "teamData" : {
   "_id" : ObjectId("554239eb4e7235204100002a"),
   "teamId" : "TB",
   "dataId" : "87c484cc-e672-4a34-ab02-cc29101d8a52",
   "teamName" : "Tampa Bay Rays",
 "teamAbbr" : "TB"
  }
}
```

Please suggest. Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2):

You can use [aggregation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/) and the [**`$eq`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/eq/#exp._S_eq) operator

```js
db.mlb_players.aggregate(
    [
        { $project: { "m": { $eq: [ "$dataId", "$teamData.dataId" ]}}},  
        { $match: { "m": true }}, 
        { $project: { "_id": 1 }}
    ]
)
```

Answer (score 0):

In first sentence you wrote that you have `players` collection, but your query looks for players in `mlb_players` collection. Maybe that is the purpose of not getting any documents...